# compute Cartesian product of 2 sets, Is it possible to force the order of elements in a set?

Tags: python

I am trying to print this set with Python

[image]

```
Cartesian_product = []
A = ['x', 'y', 'z']
B = ['1', '2', '3']
[{b,a} for b in B for a in A]
```

no matter, `{b,a}` or `{a,b}`, `for b in B for a in A` or `for a in A for b in B`, the output will alway be

```
[{'1', 'x'},
 {'1', 'y'},
 {'1', 'z'},
 {'2', 'x'},
 {'2', 'y'},
 {'2', 'z'},
 {'3', 'x'},
 {'3', 'y'},
 {'3', 'z'}]
```

is it possible to force the order of elements in this set as {'x', '1'}, {'x', '2'} ?

Comment: No, sets are unordered. You could use a tuple instead, i.e. `[(b, a) for ...`.

Comment: @Selcuk it would have to be `[(a, b) for ...]` to match the output image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The product `A × B` is the set of ordered pairs `(a, b)` where `a ∈ A` and `b ∈ B`. This is not the same as the product `B × A`, which is the set of ordered pairs `(b, a)`. You can see this using the `product` function from the `itertools` module.

```
>>> A = ['x', 'y', 'z']
>>> B = ['1', '2', '3']
>>> list(product(A, B))
[('x', '1'), ('x', '2'), ('x', '3'), ('y', '1'), ('y', '2'), ('y', '3'), ('z', '1'), ('z', '2'), ('z', '3')]
>>> list(product(B, A))
[('1', 'x'), ('1', 'y'), ('1', 'z'), ('2', 'x'), ('2', 'y'), ('2', 'z'), ('3', 'x'), ('3', 'y'), ('3', 'z')]
```

So you *must* use tuples, not sets, to represent the elements of a Cartesian product.